# sprintf annoying warning in Keil

Tags: c, keil

I am trying to use `sprintf();` function in Keil. But I have annoying warning. Let me explain my warning with example code part right below. When i debug, i get;

> warning:  #167-D: argument of type "uint8_t *" is incompatible with parameter of type "char *restrict"

And it warns me on the line about format types.

I know sprintf function is not a good solution but i really wonder why this warning show off?

Thanks

```
#include "stm32l0xx.h"  // Device header
#include <stdio.h>

void LCD_show(uint32_t  s_value)

{

  uint8_t str[9], i;

  for ( i = 0; i < 9 ; i++) str[i] = 0;

  sprintf( str, "%9ld", s_value );

}
```

Comment: What is `s_value`? It's not in your code you provided.

Comment: Sorry about difference between  s_deger and s_value they are same, i just made mistake while i was making  copy. Just changed.

Comment: `uint8_t str[9], i;` > `char str[9], i;`. Or use casting: `sprintf( (char *) str, "%9ld", s_value );`

Comment: `uint8_t str[9],` -->> `char str[10],` ... at least ...

Comment: I have 8 digits and 1 DP so i have initialized like that.

Comment: Aside from the [buffer overflow risk mentioned below by @AndrejsCainikovs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44699425/6879826), aren't you getting a warning for using `%ld` with `uint32_t`. Maybe you should turn up the warnings on your compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Fixing your warning:**

You have two options: either declare `str` as `char`, or use type casting:

```
sprintf((char *) str, "%9ld", s_value);
```

**Optimizing your code:**

The only reason you have a loop is to initialize `str` array with zeroes. Following is the code that does that in a simple, readable manner, without code overhead:

```
char str[9] = {0};
```

**Fixing your code:**

Excerpt from documentation:

> A format specifier follows this prototype:
>   %[flags][width][.precision][length]specifier
>   ...
>   Width:
>   **Minimum** number of characters to be printed. If the value to be printed is shorter than this number, the result is padded with blank spaces. The value is not truncated even if the result is larger.

This means your code eventually will get a buffer overflow and will crash. Use `snprintf`!

Comment: Code also has UB with mismatched `%ld` specifier and `uint32_t` argument.

Comment: `%ld` stands for `long int`, but `uint32_t` most likely is a typedef of `unsigned int`. I'm not totally sure you will get a warning in this particular case (perhaps depends on compiler, also not sure), since `long int` is way bigger than `unsigned int` and you will not lose any data.

Comment: But yes, the correct format specifier in this case should be just `%u`.

Comment: No. A `long` must be _at least_ 32 bits. And if it is, it cannot hold all values of a `uint32_t`. Mismatched conversion specifiers and arguments are always UB, according to the Standard. The correct thing to do is to use the `PRIu32` macro from `inttypes.h` so that the correct conversion specifer is used. There is a warning, too: **warning: format ‘%ld’ expects argument of type ‘long int’, but argument 3 has type ‘uint32_t’ [-Wformat=]**.

Comment: You are right, David. Just tested with gcc and `-Wall`, and I get the warning. The warning is off by default, btw.

Comment: Hmmm. I compiled with only default warnings (`gcc -std=c99`) to get the warning I pasted into my last comment....

Comment: I used `gcc main.c -o main -Wall` without specifying C standard. GCC 4.8.5

Comment: Note that `uint32_t` was only added to the Standard with C99, but may have been a compiler extension before that. I believe that GCC 4.8.5 defaults to C89. I wish your answer would address the `long int`-`uint32_t` mismatch, but still upvoting because you answer the warning in the question, and make an important point about buffer overflow here.

Comment: I have redifined as snprintf( str, sizeof (str), "%9ld", s_value ); i think thats for best for memory organisation.

Answer (score 0):

`uint8_t` and `char` is not necessarily the same thing. Usually actually it's typedef'd as `unsigned char`.